# R - Lag function that skips over certain row?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 Park               Date                Coy_season AC_code Aggr_Code Presence    AC AC_conducted
  <chr>              <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 3       1         1            0            0
2 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 0       1         1            0            0
3 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 4       1         1            0            0
4 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 1       1         1            0            0
5 14st NE - Coventry 2019-02-01 00:00:00          1 4       1         1            3            1
6 14st NE - Coventry 2019-02-01 00:00:00          1 2       1         1            3            1
```

Where AC_code is the treatment and varies from 0-6, 0 being a control. I would like to add a column to this dataframe, "Last_Treatment", that would indicate what the last treatment (lag of AC_code) was in each park IF another treatment preceded the event by less than 28 days AND the last treatment was not 0. If the last treatment was a 0, I would like it to skip over that 0 and look for the treatment before that, unless no other treatment had been conducted less than 28 days ago, in which case I would like it to return NA.

My ideal dataframe would therefore look like this:

```
Park               Date                Coy_season AC_code Aggr_Code Presence    AC AC_conducted Last_Treatment
  <chr>              <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>         
1 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 3       1         1            0            0 NA            
2 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 0       1         1            0            0 3             
3 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 4       1         1            0            0 3             
4 14st NE - Coventry 2019-01-30 00:00:00          1 1       1         1            0            0 4             
5 14st NE - Coventry 2019-02-01 00:00:00          1 4       1         1            4            1 1             
6 14st NE - Coventry 2019-02-01 00:00:00          1 2       1         1            4            1 4
```

I have the following code that does almost everything I want, except skipping over the 0 values:

```
Coyote_presence_2 <- Coyote_presence_2 %>%
  group_by(Park) %>% 
  mutate(Last_Treatment = if_else((Date - lag(Date))<28*60*60*24, lag(AC_code), as.character(NA)))
```

I tried the following code, but it's returning an error:

```
Coyote_presence_2 <- Coyote_presence_2 %>%
      group_by(Park) %>% 
      mutate(Last_Treatment = if_else((Date - lag(Date))<28*60*60*24, lag(AC_code > 0), as.character(NA)))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Last_Treatment`.
i `Last_Treatment = if_else(...)`.
x `false` must be a logical vector, not a character vector.
i The error occurred in group 1: Park = "14st NE - Coventry".
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
  7. dplyr::if_else(...)
  8. dplyr:::replace_with(...)
  9. dplyr:::check_type(val, x, name)
 10. dplyr:::glubort(header, "must be {friendly_type_of(template)}, not {friendly_type_of(x)}.")
```

dplyr solutions are preferred, but I would consider other suggestions!

Data available here:

```
dput(head(Coyote_presence_2))
structure(list(Park = c("14st NE - Coventry", "14st NE - Coventry", 
"14st NE - Coventry", "14st NE - Coventry", "14st NE - Coventry", 
"14st NE - Coventry"), Date = structure(c(1548806400, 1548806400, 
1548806400, 1548806400, 1548979200, 1548979200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Coy_season = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AC_code = c("3", 
"4", "4", "1", "4", "2"), Aggr_Code = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1"), Presence = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), AC = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 4), AC_conducted = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Last_Treatment = c(NA, 
"3", "4", "4", "1", "4")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    Park = "14st NE - Coventry", .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your problem is that `lag(AC_code > 0)` that will return a logical, why you get an error because you cannot return both logicals and character. However, you don't want to return a logical to get the result you're after. Instead, you could maybe replace `lag(AC_code > 0)` with something like `if_else(lag(AC_code)=="0", lag(AC_code,2), lag(AC_code))`.

Comment: If you could supply data with `dput` I'll do a solution.

Comment: Your suggestion works! I just need to link it to Date - lag(Date))<28*60*60*24 somehow. Will edit my post to supply data!

Answer (score 0):

**A solution in line with the post:**

You could continue with another nested `if_else` (see below), but you might want to explore `case_when()` to make the conditions clearer.

E.g.

```r
Coyote_presence_2x <-
  Coyote_presence_2 |>
  group_by(Park) |>
  mutate(Last_Treatment = if_else((Date - lag(Date)) < 28*60*60*24,
                                  if_else(lag(AC_code) == "0",
                                          lag(AC_code, 2),
                                          lag(AC_code)),
                                  NA_character_)) |>
  ungroup()

Coyote_presence_2x
```

**And a more general solution (see comment):**

```r
data_combined <- bind_rows(Coyote_presence_2, Coyote_presence_3)

data_combined %>%
  group_by(Park) |>
  mutate(Last_Treatment = na_if(AC_code, "0")) |>
  fill(Last_Treatment) |>
  mutate(Last_Treatment = if_else((Date - lag(Date)) < 28*60*60*24,
                                  Last_Treatment,
                                  NA_character_)) |>
  ungroup()
```

**Using corrected data (corresponding to the data presented) and constructed data for special cases (see comment):**

```r
Coyote_presence_2 <-
structure(list(Park = c("14st NE - Coventry", "14st NE - Coventry", 
"14st NE - Coventry", "14st NE - Coventry", "14st NE - Coventry", 
"14st NE - Coventry"), Date = structure(c(1548806400, 1548806400, 
1548806400, 1548806400, 1548979200, 1548979200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Coy_season = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AC_code = c("3", 
"0", "4", "1", "4", "2"), Aggr_Code = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1"), Presence = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), AC = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 4), AC_conducted = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Last_Treatment = c(NA, 
"3", "4", "4", "1", "4")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    Park = "14st NE - Coventry", .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Coyote_presence_3 <-
  structure(list(Park = c("15st NE - Coventry", "15st NE - Coventry", 
                          "15st NE - Coventry", "15st NE - Coventry", "15st NE - Coventry", 
                          "15st NE - Coventry"), Date = structure(c(1548806400, 1548806400, 
                                                                    1548806400, 1548806400, 1548979200, 1548979200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                              "POSIXt")), Coy_season = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AC_code = c("3", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    "0", "0", "1", "4", "2"), Aggr_Code = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "1"), Presence = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), AC = c(0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 4, 4), AC_conducted = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Last_Treatment = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "3", "4", "4", "1", "4")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Park = "14st NE - Coventry", .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The suggested code works in most cases, but not when I have multiple treatments coded as AC_code = 0 in a row, in which case it only looks for the prior treatment (independently of whether it's a 0 or not). Would there be a way to modify this code to make it look at the prior treatment (AC_code) that is NOT a 0? So basically lag AC_code until it finds one that isn't 0

Comment: @Gab_Laj: You can do it in many ways, but it's difficult without data showing the situations that you're interested in. See updated answer for a possible approach. If this doesn't do what you intend, please look carefully at your post and the supplied data in order to make the conditions very clear and make data that includes the difficult cases.